# best way to deploy a ttinclude file to a visual studio machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4

I have several reusable parts of my code in a .ttinclude file. I would like to make a reusable / installable visual studio add in (something like a VSIX) to deploy this file and then be able to include it in any t4 template in any project, just as if it were an assembly reference (something like being able to install the .ttinclude file to the GAC).

I already googled about it but I couldn't even find a tip on how to start doing this.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for instance use NuGet, NuGet is shipped with Visual Studio and is a pretty decent. For inspiration take a look at: https://github.com/mrange/T4Include/tree/master/NonSource/NuGet

The .nuspec file is used by NuGet to build a package and it deploys 3 ttinclude files and a sample tt file.

Hope this can help you get started.